# Search for unprotected loggers with regexps

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I have a quite large project in which one of my colleague used loggers but forgot to put "is-loggable" tests before invoking the logger, which as you know, can be substantially unefficient when using string concatenation in the log message. However, some loggers have been properly protected.

I am looking for a regexp I could use in Eclipse to search all those unprotected logger calls, but I can't find the proper regexp with a negative lookbehind to do that.

Here is some samples to make this clearer:

I want to match this:

```
logger.fine("Exception raised: " + 
    e.getClass().getName() + ". See console for details.");
```

I don't want to match this:

```
if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
    logger.fine("Exception raised: " + 
        e.getClass().getName() + ". See console for details.");
}
```

nor this:

```
if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) 
    logger.fine("Exception raised: " + 
        e.getClass().getName() + ". See console for details.");
```

I don't care to match the message content or whatever follows the logger method call (severe(), warning(), ...), all I need is to have the `logger.fine` part.

So far I have used this regexp: 
`((?<!if\s?.?logger\.isLoggable.?Level.{0,20})logger.(severe|warning|info|fine|finer|finest))` but it matches things I don't want to match. Any idea on how this could be fixed?

The code is formatted (indentation is done with tabs), meaning that we can be quite strict on our expectations.

Comment: Nobody puts a check around `logger.warning`. If your code has so many warning logs that you actually worry about performance, I think you should rethink.

Comment: @adarshr Fair enough for the warnings, but I am more interested in those fine, finer and finest methods. The project is over 500 000 lines, so it can be substantial.

Comment: I think you just passed a point of complexity where regex is no longer the right tool. I suggest a java parser, something like this: http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser . With a few lines of code, this can visit every invocation of logger.warning()/fine()/... in your codebase, and check if it's sitting inside an appropriate 'if' block. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am amazed none of the free static analysis tools I know finds this pattern (that is PMD and FindBugs). Maybe some other, more clever such tool exists?

Comment: @amir75 thanks for your comment. I was looking for a quick and dirty way of getting out of this situation using Eclipse search&replace. If I need to write code to find them, then I could use very simple methods to read and write text.

Comment: I think you can do this with a few unix commands. Try `grep -B1 -i 'logger.fine'`. Then filter only the lines which *do not* have an `if` by chaining another `grep` to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
(?<!if\s?\(logger\.isLoggable[^\n]{0,20}\n\s{0,20})logger\.fine
```

Explanation:

```
(?<!         # open negative lookbehind
if\s?\(logger\.isLoggable  # look for your if statement
[^\n]{0,20}  # then gobble up a bunch of characters ...
\n           # ... up to the end of the line
\s{0,20}     # optional whitespace at the beginning of the next line
)            # close the look behind
logger\.fine # now, is logger.fine there?
```

Comment: You can't use wildcards such as * and + inside look behind groups. However, we can use ? and {}. It seems to work if I replace the first * with a ? and then the next ones with {0,20} (what follows isLoggable never exceeds 20 chars, and there is never more than 20 tabs on the line of the loggable call. Update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Interesting. * and + wildcards do work in PCRE lookbehinds. So strange that it doesn't work in Eclipse, but I have no way to test it. I changed the answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Eclipse uses Java built-in regexp engine which is close to the one of Perl. Thanks anyway for the regexp, it works nicely.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Btw, are you saying that the `[\n]+` actually does work ok in the lookbehind?

Comment: nope, it does not (see my first comment). Could you replace that also with {0,20} to make the answer correct? Thx.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your comment. Fixed now.